# Exception when extends Pageradapter with image path from R.strings

Tags: android, string, r.java-file

I'm trying to localization for images on website.
Already I used pageradapter before localization.
I just trying to put web-image file path on R.string and take it on pageradapter.
But it generates exception.

This is my string(real address is little bit different.)

<   string name="Url"> http://~~~/content/2017/05/map.jpg<  /string>

This is my codes in pageradapter.

```
public class ChangImageClass extends PagerAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater;
OnlineImage on;
Context context;
private String changUrla =  "http://hanculture.org/content/2017/05/map.jpg";
private String changUrlab =  context.getString(R.string.Url);
```

The exception caused at "private String changUrlab =  context.getString(R.string.Url);"

Is there anybody give me a hint to solve this?
I'm not sure that 'R.strings' failed to transfer image path source or somthing else other error.
(I'm almost bignner at android and java..)

Updated exception log.
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at org.android.changdeokgung.ChangImageClass.(ChangImageClass.java:33)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at org.android.changdeokgung.MultiusedImages.onCreate(MultiusedImages.java:311)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1092)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
05-05 22:05:32.143 14361-14361/org.android.changdeokgung W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: put your exception log here

Comment: Actually there is no log because I get an exception from internet connetion try catch method on other activity. When it could get excetion, the image didn't load properly caused by internet. However when I change code on pager adater like that, it shows exception(I made it exception without code, just toast a message.)

Comment: onCreateView(){ context = getActivity();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
//you getting null object of context so you must set context
ChangImageClass pager = new ChangImageClass(getActivity());

    public class ChangImageClass extends PagerAdapter {

                //please assign your context

                LayoutInflater inflater;
                OnlineImage on;
                Context context;
                private String changUrla =  "http://hanculture.org/content/2017/05/map.jpg";
                private String changUrlab;
                public ChangImageClass(Context context){
                 this.context = context;
                 changUrlab =  context.getString(R.string.Url);
               }
    }
```

Comment: are you add this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest ?

Comment: Yap! I add permission alrady. and... I tried what you are saying... but It show me red line with "Cannot resolve method"....

Comment: It just give me with red colored character... I didn't check my exception log with null.pointer.exception it may give you some hints. I will edit my post wait a second.

Comment: I extends PagerAdapter. I posted but... it was missing, i'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Bhpat Bheda !! It works! I've just got another issue..... but anyway Your comment was works! Only except first line. I'm not sure how I can make a sentence before class... I add except that sentence and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked.Please accept my answer.You can also visit : https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private String changUrlab =  context.getResources().getString(R.string.Url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment... But I've tried that before post here... and same exception was caused....

Comment: Try to do this inside constructor as @Bhupat Bheda said.